# Ionic 3 - firebase plugin - not able to get phone's token

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, ionic3

when i am calling firebase.getToken(), It's returning undefined or null

```
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';

constructor(private firebase: Firebase) { }

...

this.firebase.getToken()
  .then(token => console.log(`The token is ${token}`)) // save the token server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
  .catch(error => console.error('Error getting token', error));

this.firebase.onNotificationOpen()
   .subscribe(data => console.log(`User opened a notification ${data}`));

this.firebase.onTokenRefresh()
  .subscribe((token: string) => console.log(`Got a new token ${token}`));
```

Installed platforms:

```
 android 8.0.0
```

Available platforms:

```
  browser ~5.0.1
  ios ~4.5.4
  osx ~4.0.1
  windows ~6.0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer.

I was not getting the token from

```
this.fcm.getToken()
```

But I got the code on token refresh using the below code:

```
this.fcm.onTokenRefresh();
```

In the native docs -v3

Get the device token

Returns: Promise Note that token will be null if it has not been established yet

Please refer the below link
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/firebase/

Actually getToken() is not at all returning any response.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. It is because platform was not ready, So did like this :

```js
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular'; 

constructor(private firebase: Firebase, private platform: Platform) {
   this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
   
      this.firebase.getToken()
        .then(token => console.log(`The token is ${token}`))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error getting token', error));

      this.firebase.onNotificationOpen()
        .subscribe(data => console.log(`User opened a notification ${data}`));

      this.firebase.onTokenRefresh()
        .subscribe((token: string) => console.log(`Got a new token ${token}`));  
        
   });
}
```

Comment: Hey,Thanks for your answer I have already mentioned the answer below, i want to know why  this.firebase.getToken() is not working. I think its a bug with ionic because i have checked  firebase , the token is already there.